# app cannot find app_width (Ruby motion query)

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

My app can't find `app_width`.

#### Error

> undefined local variable or method `app_width` for #<`MainStylesheet`:0x10b563030 ...> (NameError)

#### main_stylesheet.rb

```
class MainStylesheet < ApplicationStylesheet

  ...

  def logo_text(st)
    st.image = image.resource('logo-text')
    if landscape?

    else
      st.frame = {t: 250, w: app_width, h: 60, centered: :horizontal}
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app_width` is deprecated and has been removed in version 1.2.0.

Use `device_width` or `screen_width` instead.